# Passing data from web form (label and text) to crystal report page

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, webforms

I want to pass a value from a web form to a crystal report page. This is the code I have:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument report;  
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject X;        
report= new CrystalReport1();                         
X = report.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section1"].ReportObjects["text2"] as extObject;              
X.Text = Label3.Text;  
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CrystalReportSource1; 
CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();       
CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

The form is debugging but it gives me a message (top of crystal report viewer1):

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I need help, how can I solve it?

Comment: have u tried the code which i gave??

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using the following code !! Try This...

```
TextObject X =(TextObject)report.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section1"].ReportObjects["text2"];
X.Text = Label3.Text;
```